# Dexie.js - Filtering by multiple keys using between and a compound index

Tags: javascript, dexie

I'm trying to use a compound index of 3 attributes to filter out a range of entries using the `between()` function.

For example:

```
db.version(1).stores ({
    apps: "id,age,shoeSize,height,[age+shoeSize+height]"
});

db.table
    .where('[age+shoeSize+height]')
    .between([15, 8, 60], [20, 10, 70]);
```

I would expect the above to output entries with ages between 15-20, AND shoeSizes between 8-10 AND heights between 60-70.

However, Dexie seems to be only filtering by age here (and sorting it by ascending age) without filtering out any shoeSizes or heights that do not fall in the range that I'm querying for. There are no console errors when I run the code. Am I misunderstanding how `between` and compound indexes work? Is there any way in Dexie that I can achieve this sort of functionality?

Comment: Jared, Sorry no. Just fixed that. With that typo fixed, I still am running into the same problem.

Comment: Is there a way to see the query it produces?

Comment: Curious whether you ever managed to solved this with `between`. I'm having a pretty similar problem, and [the docs](https://dexie.org/docs/Compound-Index) seem to imply that it should work.

Comment: I'm also curious if you solved this. I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, one workaround is to filter on the `WhereClause` by one attribute (age, for example), then further filter the resulting collection object by the remaining filters. I'm wondering if there is another way to do it though, using `between()` and compound indices.